# seen feature in a android chat application

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, sockets, whatsapp

I am developing a chat application in `android` in which 2 users chat with each other, it is based on `sockets`.I want to implement the seen feature just like `facebook` or `whatsapp`.
I think may be there is an onfocus method associated with an `activity` so that whenever user opens the chat activity I can set the latest messages as SEEN in the DB, is there any focus method associated with an activity?
2-Do I have to store messages on local sqlite or on mysql remote database? If I will store on local server, how quickly I have to replicate/update remote DB?
Thanks

Comment: downvoters please comment here, I would love to correct myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android the onFocus method you talk about would be `onResume()`, which is called  whenever your Activity goes to the foreground.

Ideally the messages are stored on local database only, there's no point in replicating the messages on a remote server. However this depends on how you want to manage your chat.

Facebook, for example, is obviously server based, meaning that you can see your Facebook messages on any device just by logging in. WhatsApp, on the other hand is client based, and if you buy a new phone and install WhatsApp you don't see previous conversations' messages.

Server based messaging is more complicated because you need to replicate messages, but how often is the wrong question, because it's not time based. As soon as the user connects, you replicate, and store the last `n` messages locally.

Client based messaging doesn't need replicating, just deliver the messages and you're done. Unless you want a user to be able to send messages when his peer is offline. Then you store the messages in the server, and once the recipient connects, you forward the saved messages and delete them from the server.

Comment: Unless you want a user to be able to send messages when his peer is offline. Then you store the messages in the server, and once the recipient connects, you forward the saved messages and delete them from the server. This is what whatsapp is working, I cannot send message from User A sqlite to user B sqlite, I need some bridge

Comment: also if first time the user opens the app and he gets 1 message, the OnResume() will not be called at that time.

Comment: @user1765876 If your application knows that your Activity is in the foreground you deliver the message immediately.

Comment: I see you are refering to service point of you, I dont think I have to keep state of each message as seen or not, Since it will be seen only if user open the activity.

Comment: @user1765876 I think you still need to work on the architecture of your application, because there are many concepts that are still not clear to you.

Comment: the arch is mostly same as whatsapp, I think I have to keep a seen varaiable with each message.